# Does ClamAV scan compressed files?

Tags: clamav

I use `ClamAV` on Ubuntu 14.04, does it scan compressed files? I looked in its documentation but couldn't find anything. Also does it detect viruses that affect Microsoft Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** Yes, it does, and by default as you can see from `man clamscan`, it is turned on (the `*` indicates the default option):

```
   --scan-archive[=yes(*)/no]
          Scan  archives  supported  by  libclamav.  If  you turn off this
          option, the original files will still be  scanned,  but  without
          unpacking and additional processing.
```

**2.** The more important question you should be asking is "*Does ClamAV scan for viruses that affect Linux as well?*", because the majority of viruses ClamAV detects are Windows viruses.

Answer (score 1):

It does, but it has very conservative **limits that in practice make it silently skip archive files.**

See this thread: https://lists.clamav.net/pipermail/clamav-users/2021-December/012177.html

Below are some QUICK EXPERIMENTAL options that I hoped would give clamscan a more intuitive behavior in a single-user use case.

```
clamscan \
  --archive-verbose \
  --alert-exceeds-max=yes \
  --alert-encrypted=yes \
  --max-filesize=4095M \
  --max-scansize=4095M \
  --max-files=$[1000*1000] \
  --max-recursion=512 \
  --max-embeddedpe=256M \
  --max-htmlnormalize=256M \
  --max-htmlnotags=256M \
  --max-scriptnormalize=256M \
  --max-ziptypercg=16M \
  --pcre-max-filesize=4095M
```

However, I've found the behaviour to be spotty even then:

- You can't set any limits to 4 GB or more
- `--archive-verbose` doesn't actually print out archive members
- scanning the same set of infected files as a

  - ... **plain directory**: a ~ dozen matches in various files are produced,
  - ... **946 MB .zip file**: just one match in a single file inside the archive is reported, the rest are silently skipped
  - ... **2.1 GB .tar file**: NO matches at all are produced, not even a "Heuristics.Limits.Exceeded" warning

Unfortunately I don't have time to debug this thoroughly ATM.

It seems like clamav's main focus on (mail) server scanning has led to some restrictive behavior & hardcoded limits that cannot even be overriden by runtime parameters.